# keycloak awsume plugin not updating aws access keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, keycloak

I have configured keycloak as identity and access management for an aws account. I can login using keycloak realm url, then i created awsume plugin in python and installed and executing awsume command. awsume configuration also done at .awsume/config.yaml file.
`awsume --with-saml --role-duration 3600`
I have tested the awsume plugin and it provided the assertion as well, but when i execute that command, as expected it should update the below environment keys.

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

steps i followed for this setup:

- installed keycloak.
- created realm.
- created client by importing aws saml xml file.
- downloaded identity provider xml from realm settings.
- created identity in aws using downloaded xml file.
- created role in aws
- created identity arn,role arn and created a role in keycloak client.
- created scopes, group, user.

tried aws console login using keycloak realm url and it worked.

then installed awsume, aws cli v2, AWS CLI Session Manager Plugin and created awsume plugin, then tried awsume command and it is not updated aws access keys.

can someone help me on this issue?